# Error in a R command

Tags: r

```
tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(mach_corpus,
control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
stopwords = c("machine", "learning", stopwords("english")),
removeNumbers = TRUE, tolower = FALSE))
```

running this snippet gives the error : 
Error in sort.list(y) : invalid input 'í ½í²¯' in 'utf8towcs'

can anybody explain and please suggest the changes that need to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
library(tm)

mach_corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(c("apple banana", "banana doggy")))

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(mach_corpus,
                          control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                          stopwords = c("machine", "learning", 
                                        stopwords("english")),
                          removeNumbers = TRUE, 
                          tolower = FALSE))
```

Returns the following:

```
> tdm
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 3, documents: 2)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 4/2
Sparsity           : 33%
Maximal term length: 6
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

I suspect then, that your problem lies in the encoding of the text in your variable `mach_corpus` which is not displayed.  Probably some character in the corpus is not in utf8 and you are trying to read it with a (standard) utf8 reader.  Check the encoding of your documents.

Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6516/filtering-invalid-utf8

```
$grep -av '^.*$' file
```

or, to search through all files:

```
$grep -av '^.*$' *
```

This should find files that have non-utf8 characters, which seems to be the problem.  If you find these, it may be worthwhile to pre-process your files to remove non-utf8 characters.

Cheers,
-Scott!